# switch statement going directly to default

Tags: c++, switch-statement

In this switch, no matter what the user enter, it always skips all the cases and always displays default case!!

```
        cout << "Enter an operator(+, -, *, /)" << endl;
        cin >> oper;
        cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
        cin >> second;
        if (second > 9999)
        {
            cout << "ERROR\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            continue;
        }
        switch (oper)
        {
            case '+':
                ans = add(first, second);
            case '-':
                ans = subtract(first, second);
            case '*':
                ans = multiply(first, second);
            case '/':
                ans = divide(first, second);
            default:
                cout << "ERROR\n";
                system("PAUSE");
                continue;
        }
```

Comment: There are no `break` statements. What do you expect to happen...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't skip the cases, it enters them and then execution falls through to the next case, eventually ending up at the default case. You need to add `break` statements to break out of the `switch`:

```
    switch (oper)
    {
        case '+':
            ans = add(first, second);
            break;
        case '-':
            ans = subtract(first, second);
            break;
        case '*':
            ans = multiply(first, second);
            break;
        case '/':
            ans = divide(first, second);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have a `break` statement. The switch case will not know where to stop if you don't include these!

You can fix the code like this:

```
    cout << "Enter an operator(+, -, *, /)" << endl;
    cin >> oper;
    cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
    cin >> second;
    if (second > 9999)
    {
        cout << "ERROR\n";
        system("PAUSE");
        continue;
    }
    switch (oper)
    {
        case '+':
            ans = add(first, second);
        break;
        case '-':
            ans = subtract(first, second);
        break;
        case '*':
            ans = multiply(first, second);
        break;
        case '/':
            ans = divide(first, second);
        break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            continue;
    }
```